# JavaScript/JQuery countdown timer with multiple interval settings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, time, countdown

I want to countdown from a number, let's say 100. But I don't want the countdown to be obvious such as in seconds. I would like 3 intervals like below and if they could be random, that would be even better. Each number change, I want to setup a cookie that holds the new value.

- 2 seconds
- 8 seconds
- 14 seconds

**So it works like so:**

User lands on page, Sees the number *100*, then either 2,8 or 14 seconds later, the *100* decrements down to 99 and so on until it hits 0. Say the user sees 2 intervals and is left with *98*, that value should be set in the cookie, so when they visit the page again, the don't see 100, but the new value.

Hard, any plugins to help me?

Comment: [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [$.doTimeout()](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) jQuery Plugin along with the [$.cookie()](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.rdoc) jQuery plugin together like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var timer = ($.cookie('timer_cookie') != '') ? $.cookie('timer_cookie') : 100; // Current Timer
var intervals = [2000,8000,14000]; // Available Timer Intervals
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*intervals.length) // Random Number for Choosing Intervals

$('#timer').text(timer);
$.doTimeout('timer_id', intervals[rand], function(){
    timer = parseInt($('#timer').text()) - 1;        
    $('#timer').text(timer);
    $.cookie('timer_cookie', timer);    
return true;
});
```

This is untested but should do the trick; hope it helps!